# Is it possible to forse Skype 8 to (temporarily) use a non-standard profile data directory?

Tags: windows, console, electron, skype

I would like to have 2 skype accounts on a PC. It is also important that the profile directory for the second account is located on a non-system disk. I'm not going to run the two accounts in parallel, though this would be nice to have.

The standard place for the Skype 8 account profile is the "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\", where the %userprofile% is normally "c:\Users\User".

And I want to make Skype to look for the profile data in "f:\My_Profile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\".

The fallback solution is to use the portable Skype on the disk F, but I'd like to stick to a single instance of Skype.

My idea is to use the batch file which sets the appropriate value of %userprofile% and starts the Skype:

```
@set USERPROFILE=f:\MyProfile
@if not exist %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming @mkdir %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming
@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\Skype.exe"
```

The good news is that the Skype respects the %USERPROFILE%. At least, it creates some directories and files in the desired place.

The bad news is that something is still missing, because the GUI doesn't show up, and the console prints:

```
[Updater] initialized with fallback logger. undefined
[Updater] initialized. undefined
[Updater] start() called. undefined
[Updater] Update interval set to 14400000
[Updater] Starting unexplicit update check as the updater was started. undefined
[Updater] Checking for updates, explicit check: false undefined
[Updater] Platform updater feed URL not set. undefined
[Updater] Setting update feed url to: https://get.skype.com/s4l-update?version=8.58.0.98&os=win&ring=production&app=s4l&t=1586691142022&osversion=6.2.9200 undefined
[Updater] Checking for update. undefined
[WindowsAutoUpdater] checking for update undefined
[HttpsRequest] [2c56ff] Sending request to GET https://get.skype.com/s4l-update?version=8.58.0.98&os=win&ring=production&app=s4l&t=1586691142022&osversion=6.2.9200, Proxy: false, Attempt: 1/3 undefined
[Updater] Calling startPeriodicChecks with interval 14400000 undefined
[WindowsAutoUpdater] A try to install mandatory Updates initiated. undefined
Problem initializing the app Error: Application failed to initialize, updater was started.
    at Object.init (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\resources\app.asar\ApplicationFactory.js:48:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\resources\app.asar\Main.js:24:40)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:735:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:648:12)
    at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:5817:12)
    at Object../lib/browser/init.ts (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:5824:30)
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The missing bit was the non-existing "%userprofile%\Downloads" directory. Created it and the Skype started with the new profile.